# How do I group similar rows together and export those rows to different excel sheets?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

In the data below, how would I go about sequentially grouping the column car_part 100001 data together and put it in a different sheet and name it 100001, and then 100002 , then 100003, etc...I am not sure where to begin.

```
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'country': ['US', 'US', 'China', 'India', 'US', 'India'],
        'car_part': ['100001','100001','100002','100002','100003','100004']}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The result is something like this in excel where sheet 1 (named 100001) shows:

| country | car_part |
| --- | --- |
| US | 100001 |
| US | 100001 |

sheet 2 (named 100002):

| country | car_part |
| --- | --- |
| China | 100002 |
| India | 100002 |

Sheet 3 (named 100003):

| country | car_part |
| --- | --- |
| US | 100003 |

Sheet 4 (named 100004):

| country | car_part |
| --- | --- |
| India | 100004 |

and keeps going until all rows are finished.

Comment: Show us the expected result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grouped = df.groupby('car_part')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel_file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for name, group in grouped:
    group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="{}".format(name), index=False)
writer.save()
```